# PayPal PHP API quatity >1

Tags: paypal

I have an annoying bug when using PayPal PHP API.

In case I use Quantity = 1 for each Item object it works fine. But if I have more than one I always get a sum up error. Code written in Swedish so it Might be a bit hard to follow, Here I add Items:

```
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $i=0;              
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
              $bestallningrad[] = new Item();
              $bestallningrad[$i]->setName($row['Typ'])
                                 ->setDescription($row['Skick'])
                                 ->setCurrency('SEK')
                                 ->setQuantity($row['Antal'])
                                 ->setPrice($row['Radpris']);
              $i = $i + 1;
        }
    } else {
      mysqli_close($connection);
      $fel=2;
      echo "<SCRIPT>";
           echo "window.location.href=\"varukorg.php?Fel=$fel\";",PHP_EOL;
      echo "</SCRIPT>";
    }

    $varulista = new ItemList();
    $varulista->setItems($bestallningrad);
```

Here I create the transaction Object:

```
    $transaktioner = new Transaction();
    $transaktioner->setAmount($belopp)
                  ->setItemList($varulista)
                  ->setDescription("Beställning")
                  ->setInvoiceNumber($bid);
```

When I have Quatity >1 i get the following error:

```
    JSON: {
           "intent": "sale","payer": {
           "payment_method": "paypal"
           },
           "redirect_urls": {
           "return_url": "https://teltec.se/teltecsvar.php?lyckad=true",
           "cancel_url": "https://teltec.se/varukorg.php?Fel=5"
           },
           "transactions": [
                            {
                             "amount": {
                                        "currency": "SEK",
                                        "total": "330",
                                        "details": {
                                        "shipping": "8",
                                        "tax": "2",
                                        "subtotal": "320"
                                        }
                            },
                             "item_list": {
                                           "items": [
                                                     {
                                                      "name": "EF 80",
                                                      "description": "Begagnat",
                                                      "currency": "SEK",
                                                      "quantity": "2",
                                                      "price": "320"
               }
           ]
       },
       "description": "Best\u00e4llning",
       "invoice_number": "37"
      }
     ]
    }
```

Fel: 400
Beskrivning: {"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"transactions[0]","issue":"Item amount must add up to specified amount subtotal (or total if amount details not specified)"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"f771187267060"}

Comment: I solved the problem temporary by splitting up one row in the database that contains more than one item into several Item objects. Looks weird on PayPal side but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the price per item ("price": "160").
Eg. price * quantity should be equal to subtotal.